# Getting list item caption using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please find the below html code snippet
[image: Code snippet]
Each `<li>` element is associated with a category name (marked with green rectangle). I want to print each such category name and hence I use the following code

```
numberOfFilterCategories=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='acct-category-list']")).size();
for(int i=1;i<=numberOfFilterCategories;i++){
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='acct-category-list']/li["+i+"]/a")).getText());
 }
```

But I get output as
20
15
14 etc. What changes should I do in above code to get desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int i=1;i<numberOfFilterCategories;i++){
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='acct-category-list']"))
        .findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(i)
        .findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText());
}
```

or

```
for(int i=1;i<numberOfFilterCategories;i++){
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("acct-category-list"))
        .findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(i)
        .findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below:

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#acct-category-list>li.accnt-filtr.active+li>a"));

for(WebElement element: elems){
     System.out.println("text is "+element.getText());
}
```

if this does not give the text , use

```
ul#acct-category-list>li.accnt-filtr.active+li>a>i
```

as cssSelector.